# how can i set an unbound GridView column to invisible in code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

```
 Dim Application = From AL In db.AnnualLeave _
                    Where AL.Approval <> True _
                    Select LeaveID, EmpID, Name

    GridView3.DataSource = Application
    GridView3.DataBind()
```

after calling `GridView3.DataBind(), why do i still get

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index.

at this line of code `GridView3.Columns(1).Visible = False`   yet the grid has rows and more than 2 columns. i found a thread about similar problem here http://forums.asp.net/t/1025678.aspx/1

Note that the Gridview columns have **NOT** been defined at design time. 
`

Comment: GridView3.Columns(1).Visible = False; in which you are doing this ? Can you post complete code where you are doing and getting error

Comment: fails in both GridView3_DataBound, GridView3_RowDataBound and Page_Load

Comment: and i have a template column that i have added to the same gridview at design time. am able to hide this template column successfully in any of the above events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful where you place your code in asp.net.  If you placed that `GridView3.Columns(1).Visible = False`
code in the wrong place at the wrong time then yes, it would throw an error.

I suggest reading up on [ASP.NET Page Lifecyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)